# How to check Matrics properties are working for hystrix?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hystrix, netflix

my local.properties file hystrix properties are as bellow.

```
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.execution.isolation.strategy=THREAD
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.execution.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests=10
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=1000

hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.execution.timeout.disabled=true
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.execution.timeout.enabled=false

hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.execution.isolation.thread.interruptOnTimeout=true
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.fallback.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests=10
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.fallback.disabled=false
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.fallback.enabled=true


hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.circuitBreaker.disabled=false
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.circuitBreaker.enabled=true
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold=10
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds=8000
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage=10
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.circuitBreaker.forceOpen=false
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.circuitBreaker.forceClosed=false
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds=1000
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.metrics.rollingStats.numBuckets=5
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.metrics.rollingPercentile.enabled=true
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.metrics.rollingPercentile.timeInMilliseconds=100
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.metrics.rollingPercentile.bucketSize=10
hystrix.command.FASTSearchPageCommand.metrics.healthSnapshot.intervalInMilliseconds=100
fastSearch.executionTimeout=5000
```

So how can I check all are working. Like how can I notice that my matrics properties are working. If can give me some set of code for run and fallback method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find all documentation up here: [Hystrix docs](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use)

The example taken from their docs is following:

```
public class CommandThatFailsSilently extends HystrixCommand<String> {

    private final boolean throwException;

    public CommandThatFailsSilently(boolean throwException) {
        super(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("FASTSearchPageCommand"));
        this.throwException = throwException;
    }

    @Override
    protected String run() {
        if (throwException) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failure from CommandThatFailsFast");
        } else {
            return "success";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String getFallback() {
        return null;
    }
}
```